# Hibernate get all transaction of current year

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have a class TransactionDetails. This table holds transaction of last 10 year. Now How can i get all TransactionDetails of current year

I am using criteria as following

```
Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TransactionDetails.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entryDate", thisYear));
return (List<TransactionDetails>) criteria.list();
```

I know I can achieve this by detecting beginning of year and end of year and the do a query with between operator. But I am looking for a way do this in one line. e.g. like in sql we use `CURDATE()`

How can this be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Restrictions.between("entryDate", loDate, highDate)`

**Edit:**

You could also probably use a (vendor specific) sql restriction.

eg: `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY') = ?", "2015", StringType.INSTANCE)`

Note: This will likely perform worse than `between`

Comment: This is not what i wanted. but i guess this is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `between` restriction together with date range:

```
Calendar lowCal = Calendar.getInstance();
lowCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, lowCal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
Date lowDate = lowCal.getTime();

Calendar highCal = Calendar.getInstance();
lowCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, lowCal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
Date highDate = highCal.getTime();

Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TransactionDetails.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("entryDate", lowDate, highDate));
return (List<TransactionDetails>) criteria.list();
```

Dates are obtained by basic Java `Calendar` API. If is of course possible to obtain dates in different ways, for example using Joda Time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Restrictions.between("entryDate",fromYear, thisYear)
```

can give you what you need. Reference to [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) here

or compute the year/date 10 years before now and use

```
Restrictions.ge("entryDate",fromYearMinus10);//uses years less than 10
```